# Want aggregated data from two tables based on specific condition (SQL conditional join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables.

`T_MarkPrice`:

```
+--------+--------+-------+------------+
| FundID | Symbol | Price | Date       |
+--------+--------+-------+------------+
| 0      | DELL   | 10    | 2014-12-09 |
| 1      | DELL   | 11    | 2014-12-09 |
| 2      | DELL   | 12    | 2014-12-09 |
+--------+--------+-------+------------+
```

`T_Data`:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
| FundID | Symbol | Date       |
+--------+--------+------------+
| 1      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 |
| 2      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 |
| 3      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

I want aggregated data from both the tables in the following formats

Symbol and date are necessary conditions to match (i.e. Symbol and date of T_Data should match with `T_MarkPrice`).

`FundID` match is an optional condition, If fundID of T_Data is available in T_MarkPrice then pick Price from that row otherwise pick price from the row with fundID 0 matching date and symbol.

Here we can see that fundID 3 is not available in T_MarkPrice table, in this case we have to pick markprice with fundID 0.

Output should be following-

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------+
| FundID | Symbol | Date       | Price |
+--------+--------+------------+-------+
| 1      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 | 11    |
| 2      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 | 12    |
| 3      | DELL   | 2014-12-09 | 10    |
+--------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both the default price record and the matching record to your data record. Then show the matching price if such price exists, else show the default price.

```
select 
  d.fundid, 
  d.symbol, 
  d.date,
  coalesce(mp.price, mpdef.price) as price
from t_data d
left join t_markprice mpdef on 
  mpdef.symbol = d.symbol and mpdef.date = d.date and mpdef.fundid = 0
left join t_markprice mp on
  mp.symbol = d.symbol and mp.date = d.date and mp.fundid = d.fundid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the two tables, and use `COALESCE` to replace the `price` for the unmatched row with the value of the price for `fundId` = 0, something like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.FundID,
  d.Symbol,
  d.Date,
  COALESCE(p.price, (SELECT Price
                     FROM T_MarkPrice
                     WHERE FundID = 0)) AS Price
FROM T_Data AS d 
LEFT JOIN T_MarkPrice AS p  ON p.FundID = d.FundID 
                            AND p.Symbol = d.Symbol
                            AND p.Date = d.Date;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will make unmatched rows like the row with FundID = 3 be included in the result set, and it will have `price` = `null`, then the `COALESCE` will replace the nullable price value for these unmatched rows with the price value for the `fundid` = 0 from the `t_markprice` table.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97020/6)

This will give you:

```
| FUNDID | SYMBOL |       DATE | PRICE |
|--------|--------|------------|-------|
|      1 |   DELL | 2014-12-09 |    11 |
|      2 |   DELL | 2014-12-09 |    12 |
|      3 |   DELL | 2014-12-09 |    10 |
```